# Display confirmation message before send ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have written an `ajax` function where I want to display confirmation meeessage before submitting the form. How should I add with my condition. Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "UBRDashboard.aspx/GetDllValue",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ ddlOduModel: ddlOduModel, ddlAntModel: ddlAntModel, ddlOMTModel: ddlOMTModel, ddlSapID: ddlSapID, ddlVendorName: ddlVendorName, strReqID: r.d, ddlSapDescVal: ddlSapDescVal, SITE_ADD: SITE_ADD, LATITUDE: LATITUDE, LONGITUDE: LONGITUDE, ddlEQP_SEQ: ddlEQP_SEQ, txtLinkID: txtLinkID, RJ_QUANTITY: RJ_QUANTITY, USER_NAME: USER_NAME, CREATED_DATE: CREATED_DATE, LOCATIONTYPE: LOCATIONTYPE, TOWERTYPE: TOWERTYPE }),
                        async: true,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (r) {
                            if (r.d == "OK") {
                                alert('Record Saved successfully');
                                window.location.href = "UBRDashboard.aspx";
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
                            window.location.href = "ErrorPage.aspx";
                        }
                    })
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
                    window.location.href = "ErrorPage.aspx";
                }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to use `beforeSend` ajax property.

> beforeSend is a pre-request callback function before it is
>   sent.Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the
>   request.

```
beforeSend:function(){
     return confirm("Are you sure?");
},
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
      url: "UBRDashboard.aspx/GetDllValue",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify({ ddlOduModel: ddlOduModel, ddlAntModel: ddlAntModel, ddlOMTModel: ddlOMTModel, ddlSapID: ddlSapID, ddlVendorName: ddlVendorName, strReqID: r.d, ddlSapDescVal: ddlSapDescVal, SITE_ADD: SITE_ADD, LATITUDE: LATITUDE, LONGITUDE: LONGITUDE, ddlEQP_SEQ: ddlEQP_SEQ, txtLinkID: txtLinkID, RJ_QUANTITY: RJ_QUANTITY, USER_NAME: USER_NAME, CREATED_DATE: CREATED_DATE, LOCATIONTYPE: LOCATIONTYPE, TOWERTYPE: TOWERTYPE }),
      async: true,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      beforeSend:function(){
         return confirm("Are you sure?");
      },
      success: function (r) {
        if (r.d == "OK") {
        alert('Record Saved successfully');
        window.location.href = "UBRDashboard.aspx";
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
             alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
             window.location.href = "ErrorPage.aspx";
      }
});
```

Comment: That;s perfectly handled by the ajax..!! Working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax beforeSend callback function.

```
beforeSend: function () {
                    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
                        // do something
                    } else { 
                        // stop the ajax call
                        return false;
                    }
                },
```

See documentation Ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Write your ajax into a function like:

```
function save(){
   // something in here 
}
```

After that write a confirmation functionality, if user confirm then call save() function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this exemple is what you need ?

```
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    // Make your ajax call here
} else {
    // He refused the confirmation
}
```

Call your confirm before ajax call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your confirmation message in the `beforeSend` method : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( confirm("Do you want to Submit?")) {
    // If you pressed OK!";

 $.ajax({
  url: "UBRDashboard.aspx/GetDllValue",
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({ ddlOduModel: ddlOduModel, ddlAntModel: ddlAntModel, ddlOMTModel: ddlOMTModel, ddlSapID: ddlSapID, ddlVendorName: ddlVendorName, strReqID: r.d, ddlSapDescVal: ddlSapDescVal, SITE_ADD: SITE_ADD, LATITUDE: LATITUDE, LONGITUDE: LONGITUDE, ddlEQP_SEQ: ddlEQP_SEQ, txtLinkID: txtLinkID, RJ_QUANTITY: RJ_QUANTITY, USER_NAME: USER_NAME, CREATED_DATE: CREATED_DATE, LOCATIONTYPE: LOCATIONTYPE, TOWERTYPE: TOWERTYPE }),
  async: true,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend:function(){
     return confirm("Are you sure?");
  },
  success: function (r) {
    if (r.d == "OK") {
    alert('Record Saved successfully');
    window.location.href = "UBRDashboard.aspx";
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
         alert('Error while selecting list..!!');
         window.location.href = "ErrorPage.aspx";
  }
 });

} else {
    // If you pressed Cancel!";

}
```

Please check with [window.confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: so before ajax call, I have to write the confirm part ??

Comment: Yes, you need wrap the ajax call with this if else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently, so this is my answer, I am using jquery and jqueryconfirm, the "beforesend" callbak only allows the standard "alert" and "confirm" functions.

What I did is placing a "fake" submit button and hide the actual submit one, so it was easy dealing with the response from the custom confirm dialogs, once I got the affirmative answer from the dialog I call the "click" method of the hidden submit button.

```
...
<button id="confirmSave" type="button">Save</button>
<button id="save" class="is-hidden" type="submit"></button>
<button id="close" aria-label="close" type="reset">Cancel</button>
...
```